# Dynamically add json content with vue-if and other vue attributes

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, google-chrome-extension, vue-component

I am working chrome extension which uses vue. I have found that google can take a while to publish updates, so there is some content that I would like to be able to edit with a json that is called by the extension via a $.getJSON https request. So far, that has worked pretty well for getting raw text. But I have problems when I try to add a span tag with a v-if statement such as the following:

```
Thank you for meeting. We have prepared the following <span v-if='docCount.length > 0'>documents</span><span v-else>document</span> for you today:
```

What happens is that it just says "prepared the following 'documentsdDocuments'" as if it takes all to be true.

I have gotten this result after putting the above JSON text in a v-html as follows:

```
<p v-html="coverLetterContent['p1']"></p>
```

I have gotten the same result after trying the following:

```
.bind(this)).then( function (result){
      $(".letter-body").append("<p>"+result["letter"]["p1"]+"</p>")
    });
```

I also tried creating a dynamic component as follows but was getting an error and nothing was rendered:

```
dynamicComponent: function() {
      return {
        template: `<p>${coverLetterContent["p1"]}</p>`,
        methods: {
          someAction() {
            console.log("Action!");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The error I got on this was: "ReferenceError: coverLetterContent is not defined." coverLetterContent is defined in the vue app data and is accessible via the v-html call described above.

Comment: Just want to point out that this `> 0` should probably be `> 1`

Comment: @SebastianVittersø there is always one document in this context which is why I want it to say plural "documentS" if > 0. Regardless, I just tested by putting 1 in the JSON and it was the same result.

Comment: Just thinking: If there's always at least one, the `> 0` will always be true, so there's no point to it. I would also point out that it's quite messy to use JQuery to change the DOM-tree while using Vue to render it, you might want to abstain from that.

Comment: @SebastianVittersø docCount often is 0. I was just saying the user always gets one other document not accounted for in docCount. So this is to cover the singular and plural context only. Not zero. Thanks for the jquery note. That does seem like the least plausible of the three attempted methods.